# Cannot access Google Cloud Compute Instance External IP

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have set up an Google Cloud Compute Instance:

- Machine type

  - n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory)
- CPU platform

  - Intel Haswell
- Zone

  - us-east1-c

I can ssh in using the external address.

I have installed the `vncserver` and can access it on port 5901 from localhost as well as the internal IP.

I am trying to access it from the static, external IP address but it is not working.

I have configured the firewall to open to port to **0.0.0.0/0**, but it is not reachable.

Can anyone help?

------after further investigation from the tips from the two answers (thanks, both!), I have a partial answer:

> The Google Cloud Compute instance was set, by default, to not allow
>   HTTP traffic.  I reset the configuration to allow HTTP traffic.  I
>   then tried the troubleshooting tip to run a small HTTP service in
>   python.  I was able to get a ressponse from the service over the
>   internet.

The summary of the current situation is as follows:

- The external IP address can be reached
- It is enabled and working for SSH
- It is enabled and working for HTTP
- It does not seem to allow traffic from `vncserver`

Any idea how to configure the compute instance to allow for `vncserver` traffic?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I can ping the external IP from a computer outside the Google Cloud network

Comment: Can you paste your firewall settings here? Also, try to start a simple HTTP server with "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80", try to access it from the internet.

Comment: The fire wall rules from the Google Cloude Network console are: 

> default-allow-icmp 0.0.0.0/0 icmp Apply to all targets 
default
 
> default-allow-internal 10.128.0.0/9 tcp:0-65535, 2 more Apply to all targets 
default
 
--default-allow-rdp 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:3389 Apply to all targets 
default
 
--default-allow-ssh 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:22 Apply to all targets 
default
 
--vnc-server 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:5901 vnc-server 
default

Comment: and I started a simple HTTP server using "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80". Can't access from the internet.

Comment: // , This might sound nitpicky, but would you be willing to rephrase this as a question? It can really help out the noobs who might be coming to Stack Overflow for the first time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you already verified that [Google Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking) or your VM are not blocking packets, you must make sure that VNC service [is configured](https://serverfault.com/questions/350527/how-to-specific-listening-ip-of-vnc-server-under-linux) to listen on the [external IP address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54975/how-to-check-that-a-daemon-is-listening-on-what-interface).

You can always use a utility like [nmap](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) outside Google project to reveal information on the port status.

Comment: I ran netstat -antup....and see the following:
.
.
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5902            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2634/Xtightvnc  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2634/Xtightvnc  
.
.

Comment: 5902? The firewall is open for 5901?

Comment: I learned, just before posting the comment that vncserver changes the port depending on the display it assigned.  It takes a range from 5900 - 5909, as I understand.  I have update the firewall accordingly.

Comment: // , This was the problem with our instance. Thanks for the tip, @Carlos.

Answer (score 5):

enable http/https traffic form the firewall as per the need. it will work!!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to having the firewall rules to [allow HTTP traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51437065/5279996) in both Google Cloud Platform and within the OS of the instance, **make sure you install a web server** such as Apache or Nginx.

After installing the web server, you connect to the instance using SSH and verify you do not get a failed connection with the following command:

```
$ sudo wget http://localhost
```

If the connection is positive, it means that you can access your external URL:

```
http://<IP-EXTERNAL-VM>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused

I am using Container-optimized-OS. Can you suggest what might be wrong?

Comment: You have to make sure that the port you are trying to access is open, otherwise you should open it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51437065/5279996. It is a very common mistake regardless of what you want to display (OS, app server, etc), therefore, treat it as a generic problem and not something specific to Container-optimized-OS.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new firewall rule to allow other port where you app is running.
For me this thing works:

1. Go to the GCP Console.[Go to firewall policies](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-security/firewall-manager/firewall-policies/list?_ga=2.43952549.1020111134.1697189724-492498021.1677671767)
2. Click Create firewall rule.
3. Enter a Name for the firewall rule.
   This name must be unique for the project.
4. Under “Targets”, select “All instances in the network”.
5. Under “Source IP ranges”, enter 0.0.0.0/0 to allow traffic from any IP address.
6. Under “Protocols and ports”, enter tcp:8080 to allow traffic on port 8080 (assuming your app listens on port 8080).
   Click “Create”.

now you can access your app with its IP. ex: IP:port

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud Compute instance was set, by default, to not allow HTTP traffic. I reset the configuration to allow HTTP traffic. I then tried the troubleshooting tip to run a small HTTP service in python. I was able to get a response from the service over the internet.

As such, the original question is answered, I can access Google Cloud Compute Instance External IP.  My wider issue is still not solved, but I will post a new, more specific question about this issue

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: make sure you are requesting **`http`** not **`https`**

In my case i was following the link from my CE instance's `External Ip` property which takes you directly to the `https` version and i didn't set up https, so that was causing the 'site not found' error.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are two main things to check.

```
1. Port
```

By default, only `port 80, 443 and ICMP` are exposed. If your server is running on a different port, create a record for the same.

```
2. Firewall
```

Make sure you are allowing http and https traffic based on your need. 
oua re

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I set up the traffic for the firewall rule to be 'Egress' instead of 'Ingress'.

Answer (score 0):

Create an entry in your local ssh config file as below with mentioned local forward port. In my case its an example of yarn's IP, which I want to access in browser.

```
Host hadoop
     HostName <External-IP>
     User <Local-machine-username>
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<private-key-for-above-user>
     LocalForward 8089 <Internal-IP>:8088
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone already initiated 'https'
just disable it and check again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).