# Public Static IP for google VM

Tags: web-services, networking, network-programming, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have a google VM. I got public as well for the same (using which I am RDP'ing to that VM). But when I am trying to access any webservice hosted in VM from outside world using ip:port, it is not connecting to that webservice.

To be more precise : 
I have hosted a sample webservice using nodejs on port 8080.
I have tried accessing http://:8080 .  No luck. But it is working with localhost:8080 inside VM.

I have googled about external ip etc, but all went out of my head. Can any one please help me how to resolve this issue ? do I need to make any config changes etc? if yes, could you please provide me the required steps.

Update :
 I have created fire wall rule saying : port : allow all, target tags : all instances, IP : 0.0.0.,0/0 . even then it is not working.

OS : windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access Google Cloud Compute Instance External IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050596/cannot-access-google-cloud-compute-instance-external-ip)

Comment: OS : windows 10

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the GCP firewall rules are applicable on the network level. You might need to configure the virtual machine specific firewall rules (according to the OS you are using). For example, in CenOS you may need to use firewall-cmd commands to configure the internal firewall.

Comment: oh, any idea for windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this. All the time I was thinking to enable port in networks for google cloud, but the problem is at my windows firewall. once I disabled it, I could access my webserver from outside environment.