# Unable to connect externally to Snap application running on google cloud

Tags: haskell, google-cloud-platform, haskell-stack, haskell-snap-framework

I'm trying to run my [project](https://github.com/AHaliq/nonosolver) on google cloud. The server is run with `quickHttpServe` which runs on `http://0.0.0.0:8000`. I've ssh'ed into my cloud instance, cloned my repo, install stack, built the project, and able to run it on the cloud instance.

It works fine on my local machine and am able to receive html file from the server on `http://localhost:8000` but not on `http://<my cloud instance external ip>:8000`.

I'd like to be able to go to `http://<my cloud instance external ip>:8000` and be served a html page as how it works when i run it locally on my machine.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050596/cannot-access-google-cloud-compute-instance-external-ip

Would be useful to check ports are opened and not blocked by a firewall (iptables etc).

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I've added a firewall rule under the VPC network tab in google cloud for ip range `0.0.0.0/0` for `tcp:8000` still to no avail, I'm getting `35.240.220.33 took too long to respond` on the browser when i go to `http://35.240.220.33:8000` (my external ip). I've also enabled http and https traffic.

Comment: Please add the output of `netstat -tlp`

Comment: Hmm http://35.240.220.33:8000/ is working for me though? "Nonogram Solver in Haskell" probably that VPC filter took a minute or two to activate.

Comment: Wow! ok so it works on 4g I'm able to access it on my phone, but not on my laptop's wi-fi connection.

Comment: I believe its working now so this question may be closed, you may post the firewall ports as the answer as i think that might be the original issue

Comment: @iluvAS can you add the firewall rules comment as and answer? so we can upvote it and accepted and close this as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a firewall rule under the VPC network tab in google cloud for ip range `0.0.0.0/0` for `tcp:8000` seems to solve the issue.